# PHP Smarty Insert functions and variables

Tags: php, smarty

I have this smarty template, I need to call a function from my file.

Everything works fine, php recognizes the parameters, but not the values of the smarty variables. 
Code:

```
{insert name=file_details value=a assign=fd fid=$m[i].FID}
<ul class='list'>
    {section name=x loop=$fd}
        {insert name=gfs assign=afs a=$fd[x]}
        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/files/{$fd[x].FID|md5}{$fd[x].s}/{$fd[x].fname}" target="_blank">
        {$fd[x].fname} <b>[{$afs}]</b>
        </a></li>
    {/section}
</ul>
```

Meaning. 
the first insert retrieves some file information from my database, using as parameter $m[i].FID everything works fine, when I tell him for example {$fd[x].fname} it displays the name of the file, but when I tell him {insert name=gfs assign=afs a=$fd[x]} and make a var_dump(a) in the function insert_gfs all the values appear as null.

Any help would be great, I don't know what i'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are writen as `$m.i` in Smarty. Not `$m[i]`.

If you replace all your array notations like this, it should work.

```
{insert name=file_details value=a assign=fd fid=$m.i.FID}
<ul class='list'>
    {section name=x loop=$fd}
        {insert name=gfs assign=afs a=$fd.x}
        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/files/{$fd.x.FID|md5}{$fd.x.s}/{$fd.x.fname}" target="_blank">
        {$fd.x.fname} <b>[{$afs}]</b>
        </a></li>
    {/section}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, at the end, I had to rewrite that function, it apparently was failing to get the parammeters when i called  
{insert name=gfs assign=afs a=$fd.x}